# Sentence2vec and Word2vec involving stop words and Named Entities

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, sentence-similarity

I'm working on a NLP project, involving sentence2vec. I'm presuming I would be using pre-trained word embeddings for converting tokens into vectors and then proceeding to sentence embedding.

Since my sentence involves : 
stop words like **can't, won't, aren't** etc. which *NLTK* would reduce to **{ca, wo, are} + not**. 
 So I can't reduce them, and I don't want to remove them as stop words since sentences like mentioned below, should have different embedding.

**My name is Priyank 

My name is not Priyank**

Another Important doubt is that how to incorporate Named entities such as the name of a person like **Mark K. Hogg** in my sentence vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the ones you do not want to be as stop words from this [list](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sebleier/554280/raw/7e0e4a1ce04c2bb7bd41089c9821dbcf6d0c786c/NLTK's%2520list%2520of%2520english%2520stopwords)

```
# Open a file and read it into memory
file = open('words.txt')
text = file.read()

# Apply the stoplist to the text
clean = [word for word in text.split() if word not in stoplist]
```

Comment: How do you propose I account for named entities such as Indian Name, which doesn't have a word2vec embeddings.

Comment: The names will also be considered like any other word. It's better you train your own word2vec if you want to use. If you don't have enough data better identify those names using named entity recognition and replace those words with some common word. Anyhow they are not going add any value for your semantic match.

Comment: If the use case is like the one mentioned above tfidf works better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try, will comment here if Im unable to resolve the conflict regarding the Named entites. Just one last doubt, For the names, whose embedding is not present in word2vec vocabulary, should I remove them or replace them with words like "he/she"

Comment: Replace them with some common word like name for all